# onclick of a <a> tag, open in new tab another html file

Tags: html, css

When the  tag is clicked, I want it to open another .html file (for example could be called discussions.html) in another tab.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body>

<a href="<!--I don't know what to put here pls help-->">open new html file</a>


</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You just have to set the target of the link to blank, that's all.
See below:

```
<html>
<head>
<body>

<a href="discussions.html" target="_blank">DISCUSSIONS</a>

</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to open link in a new tab:

```
<a href="https://example.com" target="_blank">some text</a>
```

Or for page in your domain:

```
<a href="example.html" target="_blank">some text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to put a link inside there ^^

e.g. /dist/discussion.html"   if you want to make it point on another one of your websites
in this project

or http://google.com        if you want it to redirect to another existing site